# stacked bar plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with 4 column year, hour, pm, Year_01 such as

```
year    hour    pm      Year_01    
2000    00:30   20.056  2000     
2000    01:30   20.399  2000.   
2000    02:30   19.997  2000.     
2000    03:30   17.965  2000.      
2000    04:30   14.653  2000.     
2000    05:30   12.39   2000.   
2000    06:30   11.447  2000.  
2000    07:30   10.954  2000.     
2000    08:30   10.658  2000.  
2000    09:30   10.538  2000  
2000    10:30   10.684  2000   
2000    11:30   11.252  2000  
2000    12:30   12.254  2000  
2000    13:30   13.199  2000  
2000    14:30   14.117  2000  
2000    15:30   14.987  2000  
2000    16:30   15.795  2000  
2000    17:30   16.54   2000     
2000    18:30   17.24   2000     
2000    19:30   17.886  2000  
2000    20:30   18.466  2000  
2000    21:30   19.018  2000  
2000    22:30   19.517  2000  
2000    23:30   19.954  2000  
2001    00:30   38.571  2001  
2001    01:30   38.913  2001  
2001    02:30   38.32   2001  
2001    03:30   35.921  2001  
2001    04:30   31.761  2001  
2001    05:30   27.905  2001  
2001    06:30   30.53   2001  
2001    07:30   28.638  2001  
2001    08:30   27.447  2001  
2001    09:30   26.662  2001  
2001    10:30   26.75   2001  
2001    11:30   27.611  2001  
2001    12:30   28.978  2001  
2001    13:30   30.294  2001  
2001    14:30   31.521  2001  
2001    15:30   32.62   2001  
2001    16:30   33.604  2001  
2001    17:30   34.478  2001  
2001    18:30   35.272  2001  
2001    19:30   35.98   2001  
2001    20:30   36.602  2001  
2001    21:30   37.186  2001  
2001    22:30   37.71   2001  
2001    23:30   38.154  2001
```

I Want to plot stacked br plot. I used

```
ggplot(data=data2, aes(x=year, y=pm, fill=hour)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But it's not giving the correct plot. Y axis also showing values more than 40. So please correct the code.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is your expected result, but you might add `position = "dodge"` to `geom_bar`. It will change default stack positioning to dodge (side by side).

Comment: thanks for the reply. if you look at the y axis the values are upto 800 but the given data (pm) is upto maximum 38. So I want values upto 40 in y axis. And I want green colour at the bottom because during that time the values (pm) are very less.

Comment: You made a stacked plot, which means all the values of `pm` are stacked on top of each other for a given year.  The y axis is based on the total sum of `pm` for the `year` (which apparently is ~400 and ~800), not the maximum value of `pm` in the dataset.  Maybe you want a different kind of plot?

Comment: okay, I think I got confused with this stack plot. thanks for the clarification. So is it possible this type of bar plot with colour shading on the basis of hours and y axis on <pm> data basis